# c# Nunit to get all ignored test count and names

Tags: c#, attributes, nunit

I am using c# and Nunit testing framework.

I have to get count and names of all ignored test cases.

Tried to check using testcontext and i am able to get single name of test case.
But i want to count of all ignored test cases within my project and names of those test cases.

```
[Test]
[Ignore("Global not supported")]
public void AddUser()
{

}
```

I am ignoring tests as above mentioned on the code. I have many tests in my project which are ignored. can you please check help

Comment: NUnit's `TestContext` represents the context of a __single test__. It's not suitable to use for getting info about __all__ the tests. To get summary info, you have to use the output that is saved after all the tests are run. How to do it depends on how which runner you are using. You should give us that information to get an answer.

Comment: I am using Nunit test Adapter in short Nunit runner so whatever tests are ignored those are not displayed anywhere. Does nunit runner generates default report and where it saves. In my case i have not seen any report which has output of all tests saved after complete execution

Comment: Actually, there are about several NUnit runners, not counting 3rd party. The NUnit test adapter is one of them. It's helpful if you always say what runner you are using because some features come from the framework and others from the particular runner. I can try to answer now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the test adapter under Test Explorer, ignored tests appear in the display marked as warnings. NUnit considers ignored tests to be a **Bad Thing**, which is why you get a warning. Ideally, you should not ignore tests in NUnit unless you want them to be considered as **Bad**! (There are, of course, other ways to skip tests that are neutral as far as the outcome goes.)

So, if you are using Test Explorer to run the tests, you should be seeing those warnings. If you group tests by Outcome, you will see a total. Test Explorer also provides a general summary by Outcome. However, AFAIK, there is no report suitable for printing.

If you are running tests using some other runner (not Test Explorer), which makes use of the NUnit adapter, then the summary you see will depend on what that runner provides.

What NUnit itself **does** provide is a summary report in XML format (defaults as **TestResult.xml**), which you can use to produce any desired report. All the info is there. There are a number of third-party products that can produce a report from this XML or you can write a simple program yourself.